# SQL Server Express se cierra

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy tratando de abrir mi diagrama entidad relación, previamente hecho en SQL Server Expres.
Pero SQL se me esta cerrando cuando intento abrirlo, **simplemente se cierra y se abre nuevamente y no me aparece ningún error**.

Alguien ha experimentado algo similar que me pueda ayudar.

La versión que estoy utilizando del "**SQL Server Management Studio**" es la 15.0.18330.0

Espero alguien me pueda ayudar.

Saludos

DS

Comment: SQL se me esta cerrando que significa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dentro de la rama de administración tienes un log de lo que ha ocurrido en Sql server, que te puede dar información.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego en la carpeta de C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQLXX.YYYY\MSSQL\Log
Donde xx corresponde a la versión del motor e YYYY a la instancia, tienes archivos de logs, donde te pueden mostrar más información de lo que ha podido ocurrir.

Además también graba información en el registro del sistema.(Visor de eventos).

No obstante, dado que el management Studio es sólo un cliente, independiente del motor, puedes actualizarlo a la versión, por ejemplo 17.4 muy estable. La última es la 18.5, que es la que te dejo en el enlace.

Dentro de la página puedes navegar, para ir a versiones anteriores.

Muy importante descargar desde el idioma que te corresponda (Windows).

[Download SSMS](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder echare un vistazo a lo que comentas.